# Actionsheet issue on upgrading to Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactionsheet

I have been developing my application on xcode 3.2 for a while now and it was working great.

With the new IOS 5, i finally decided to upgrade to Xcode 4.2.
So i've opened up my project and it compiles great, however i've run into two problems i cant seem to fix.

One is that when i display a actionsheet, it works perfectly until you hit one of the buttons. Then the actionsheet disappears and your left with just a faded view.
My code for the actionsheet is

```
UIActionSheet *ActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Actionsheet" 
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil      
otherButtonTitles:@"Actionsheet","Action", nil];
[ActionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [ActionSheet release];






-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{

NSString *ActionSheet = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if ([ActionSheet isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
    NSLog(@"Nothing");
}
else {
   NSString *ActionSheetResult=ActionSheet;
   }
   }
```

This worked perfectly in xcode 3.2, just not xcode 4.2

My other issue is with openflow, the open source coverflow libary. It worked fine on xcode 3.2 but now on xcode 4.2 it does not seem to animate as well, i was wondering if anyone knows of a way to fix this? Its a problem with the framework code not being compatible with IOS5.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hello, I have got the open flow working through another question on this site, however still have a problem with the action sheet, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure youve got the action sheet delegate at the top of your view `controller.h` file

```
@interface UIViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
```